# Novel about a world where people all have an egg they grow up with, which hatches at 16 years old

Tags: story-identification, novel

I saw a recap video on YouTube of this novel and am really hoping it's not an A.I. generated story. The settings is a world where people all have an egg they grow up with and have to hatch. The egg hatches at 16 years old. The main character named Xu Su hatches a purple zombie, which is the weakest creature. But he has a "system" and it allows him to make it grow and evolve to be extremely strong.

I have tried looking it up every way I can think of but absolutely no luck.

Edit: I was informed I can add the video link in case it helps anyone, so, here ya go.

Comment: Is the video still in your YouTube watch history or browser history?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, the characteristics of "seemingly weak character who is secretly the strongest" and "has a 'video game'-style system" are so common and cliché that it hardly matters whether it is AI-generated. I suppose they are thought to move inventory because they appeal to the *presumed* characteristics of the supposed audience of basement-dwelling otaku?

Comment: *"[I] am really hoping it's not an A.I. generated story"* -- I never thought I'd live to see this day. And it's worse than I ever imagined. Well, scifi always warned of tech being used to spam or make human lives more miserable :/

Comment: @MiloP yes, and I already looked for a novel name or author or comment section knowledge or anything and there is nothing. It's a tiny youtube channel.

Comment: @Adamant I'm trying to be polite when I say this and I'm not saying you are wrong about how common it is, but so what?? Its okay to like "cliche" basic styles of something and look for the truly good or interesting ones in all the rabble. Know what I mean? For ME, this one stood out in a good way. This kind of story is my current "itch" so I'll just enjoy listening or reading stuff that makes me happy, because I just like to be happy :)

Comment: @AndresF. I know right!? I listen to a ton of stories while I work (overnight shift life) and I can usually tell but a few have been really good and turned out to be A.I. generated. I almost wouldn't actually care as long as I enjoy the marriage but most ai storries can't continue themselves so you get what you get.

Comment: Wow! Do you have an example of one you know to be A.I. generated (and good)? I've long suspected most of the crap pulled on us by Netflix et al could easily be autogenerated, if there's mostly not a shred of originality anymore, simple rehashing of past successes (and even past failures!). In any case, upvoted your question (and I haven't the faintest idea about the answer).

Comment: @EvolvedDesign If you still have access to the video, you might consider adding it to the question so answerers can take a look too. Every piece of info helps!

Comment: @Andres: [This one](https://aibusiness.com/nlp/author-reveals-using-chatgpt-for-award-winning-novel) made headlines. Admittedly, it's one of the "better" examples in that it was used for inspiration, and then human-edited.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots wow, the Akutagawa Prize is really prestigious (I've read lots of novels that won it, since I'm into Japanese literature). It says they'll review the conditions for submissions, I'm guessing to exclude Gen AI. In my opinion, books should be written by humans -- not because AI cannot produce interesting things, but because the human author is important and meaningful *to me*. I guess other people complained about the advent of other tools, but this is my time to complain -- and my right.

Comment: (On the other hand, Philip Dick is said to have used the I Ching to write parts of The Man in the High Castle, and is that so different from using Gen AI? I wonder, I don't have the answer...)

Comment: Well, at least "The beast transformation descends,Everyone will become the animals" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvtithYBmR0) the thumbnail (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IvtithYBmR0/maxresdefault.jpg) has the name, so at least one of them exists?: https://mtlfanfic.com/manga/global-beast-transformation-only-i-know-the-law-of-beast-transformation/

Comment: Well, it's similar to https://wuxiaworld.site/novel/what-you-want-to-use-my-music-to-hatch-dragon-eggs/ - Except that one has music hatching instead of just time, and also dragon eggs not just regular eggs?

Comment: And "Devouring Is Evolving: My Reincarnation As An Arctic Wolf" seems to match https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38V9Ibj8v6Y (I was reborn as an Arctic wolf, and all the creatures of the Arctic bowed down to me.)